# Does Hamachi give you a working public IP address?

Tags: hamachi

I know that in your VPN Hamachi gives you something from the 5.0.0.0/8 range. Its not official and its not private so in theory this is publically accessable, but I'm not sure

Is the IP address that Hamachi gives you a public address that you can access from the public non-hamachi internet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's basically the same as an IP address on a private network; it's not exposed to the public Internet.

Comment: And whats more, they don't have any right to issue addresses in that range, it doesn't belong to them, so they cannot be routed on the internet even if they wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

The 5.x.x.x address space that Hamachi assigns to you is currently officially a public address range and addresses like these are assigned to new node on the Internet.
So Hamachi is now in CONFLICT with real computers on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address that you're given when you join their network is the same as you would receive when joining a LAN with a DHCP Server (router). You're most likely given a 192.168.x.x or 10.0.x.x address. Think of the Hamachi addresses like these. When nodes join the same network as each other, they're given permission to see one another (similar to having multiple routers, one for each hamachi network.)

Comment: You're never given a 192.168.0.0/16 or 10.0.0.0/8 address. Hamachi uses the 5.0.0.0/8 block.

Comment: That is not true when using Hamachi as a Gateway Network.